# How to displaystyle all the formulas without typing displaystyle everywhere?

Tags: formatting, displaystyle

How show all the formulas with displaystyle,avoinding typing repeteadly \displaystyle?

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}


\begin{document}
Without any \emph{displaystyle}
$
  \frac{5+\frac{2}{5+\frac{2}{5}}}{5-\frac{2}{5-\frac{2}{5}}}
$

With any \emph{displaystyle}
$
  \frac{5+\displaystyle{\frac{2}{5+\frac{2}{5}}}}{\displaystyle{5-\frac{2}{5-\frac{2}{5}}}}
$

With more \emph{displaystyle}
$\displaystyle{
  \frac{5+\displaystyle{\frac{2}{5+\frac{2}{5}}}}{\displaystyle{5-\frac{2}{5-\frac{2}{5}}}}
}$

\textbf{How to use displaystyle in all the expresion withou typing displaystyle repeteadly in all the fractions/sqrt?}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\everymath` could be your friend here, but I doubt that it is very reasonable to use `\displaystyle` everywhere

Comment: You could as well use `\DeclareMathSizes{10pt}{10pt}{10pt}{10pt}`

Comment: Why don't you use `\dfrac`  or `\cfrac`?

Comment: why are you using _inline_ math not display math,  you wouldn't need `\displaystyle` at all if you set this as a math display.